# How should I create that implicit rating-matrix with python?

Tags: python, dataset, recommendation-engine, rating

I'm doing research on a recommendation system using the Gowalla dataset. However, the dataset has no location rating so I must generate that data into an implicit rating with a value of '1' for those who have visited the location and '0' for those who have never visited the location. How should I create that matrix with python?
[This is a Gowalla dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97FFA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code should do what you are asking. It creates a sparse rating matrix (scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) having number of rows equals to the number of distinct users and number of columns equals to the number of distinct locations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

#Load dataset
df = pd.read_csv('gowalla.csv', sep='\t', names=['user_id','','','','location_id'])

# Group interactions
users_locations = df.groupby(by=['user_id','location_id']).apply(lambda x: 1).to_dict() 

# Number of different Users / Locations
nu = len(df['user_id'].unique())
nl = len(df['location_id'].unique())

# Build Rating matrix
row, col = zip(*(users_locations.keys())) #row-> users,  col-> locations
map_u = dict(zip(df['user_id'].unique(),range(nu)))
map_l = dict(zip(df['location_id'].unique(),range(nl)))
row_idx = [map_u[u] for u in row]
col_idx = [map_l[l] for l in col]
data = np.array(users_locations.values(), dtype=np.float32)
rating_matrix = csr_matrix((data, (row_idx, col_idx)), shape=(nu,nl))
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But, i can run this code because of library. what library do you use? just pandas or any other library?

Comment: I edited the answer with the import. Library used are pandas, scipy and numpy. The code works in Python 2.7.9